# Memory Leak Issue with setText (Possibly?)

Tags: java, android, opencv, memory-leaks

I'm working on a basic application that tells the user the amount of contours in the video feed in real time using OpenCV.  I have this working, but about a minute into running the application closes and there are no logcat errors.  I'm a new developer, but through some research believe this is a memory-leak issue.  I think it has something to do with setting the text on each video frame.  Here is my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
    static {
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Unable to load OpenCV");
        }
        else {
            Log.d("SUCCESS", "OpenCV loaded");
        }
    }

    private TextView contourCount;

    //TAG for log
    private static final String TAG = "Contour Count";

    //Mats for image processing
    private Mat mRgba;
    private Mat mGray;
    //Declare the cameraview
    private JavaCameraView openCvCameraView;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //OpenCv
    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                //Turn on cameraview
                openCvCameraView.enableView();
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
            }
        }
    };

    //OnResume handling
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        openCvCameraView.enableView();
    }

    //OnCreate tasks
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Keep the screen on while app is running
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        //Set layout and initialize cameraView
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        openCvCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.HelloOpenCvView);
        openCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        openCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        openCvCameraView.enableView();
    }

    //Handling onPause tasks - Disable Camera
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (openCvCameraView != null)
            openCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    //Handling onDestroy tasks - Disable Camera
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (openCvCameraView != null)
            openCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    //New Mats for first onFrame
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        //Initialization of variables used for video analysis
        mGray = new Mat();
        mRgba = new Mat();
    }

    //Release the Mats when camera is stopped
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        mGray.release();
        mRgba.release();
    }

    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
        mGray = inputFrame.gray();

        Mat imageHSV = new Mat(mRgba.size(), Core.DEPTH_MASK_8U);
        Mat imageBlurr = new Mat(mRgba.size(), Core.DEPTH_MASK_8U);
        Mat imageA = new Mat(mRgba.size(), Core.DEPTH_MASK_ALL);
        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, imageHSV, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imageHSV, imageBlurr, new Size(5,5), 0);
        Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(imageBlurr, imageA, 255,Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY,7, 5);

        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        Imgproc.findContours(imageA, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        setContours(contours.size());

        return mRgba; 
    }

    public void setContours(final int level) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {

                contourCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contourLevel);
                contourCount.setText("" + level);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

The same issue occurs if I declare contourCount in `onCreate()`.  I'm not sure if it has something to do with making level final in the method call for `setContours()`, but I have also tried to solve this using a handler that is declared in `onCreate()` and sending a message to it with the `contours.size()` within `onCameraFrame()` but this also causes the same issue.  What am I doing wrong?  How can I avoid this in the future?  I am new to this so please be detailed in explaining the issue and future avoidance.

Thank you in advance! :)

EDIT SOLVED:

Figured it out. Thanks to everyone who contributed.  Here is the working code for anyone interested or those with the same issue in the future!

The fix comes from releasing the Mats used in onCameraFrame

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
import org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView;
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.Size;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {
    static {
        if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
            Log.d("ERROR", "Unable to load OpenCV");
        }
        else {
            Log.d("SUCCESS", "OpenCV loaded");
        }
    }

    //TAG for log
    private static final String TAG = "Contour Count";

    //Mats for image processing
    private Mat mRgba;
    private Mat mGray;
    private Mat imageHSV;
    private Mat imageBlurr;
    private Mat imageA;
    private Mat hierarchy;
    //Declare the cameraview
    private JavaCameraView openCvCameraView;
    private static String level;

    private static TextView contourCount;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    //OpenCv
    private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
        @Override
        public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
            {
                Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV loaded successfully");
                //Turn on cameraview
                openCvCameraView.enableView();
            } break;
            default:
            {
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
            } break;
            }
        }
    };

    //OnResume handling
    @Override
    public void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();
        openCvCameraView.enableView();
    }

    //OnCreate tasks
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.i(TAG, "called onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Keep the screen on while app is running
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

        //Set layout and initialize cameraView
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_main);
        openCvCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.HelloOpenCvView);
        openCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
        openCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
        openCvCameraView.enableView();

        contourCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.contourLevel);
    }

    //Handling onPause tasks - Disable Camera
    @Override
    public void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        if (openCvCameraView != null)
            openCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    //Handling onDestroy tasks - Disable Camera
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (openCvCameraView != null)
            openCvCameraView.disableView();
    }

    //New Mats for first onFrame
    public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
        //Initialization of variables used for video analysis
        mGray = new Mat();
        mRgba = new Mat();
    }

    //Release the Mats when camera is stopped
    public void onCameraViewStopped() {
        mGray.release();
        mRgba.release();
    }

    //onCameraFrame image processing
    public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
        mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();

        imageHSV = new Mat(mRgba.size(), Core.DEPTH_MASK_8U);
        imageBlurr = new Mat(mRgba.size(), Core.DEPTH_MASK_8U);
        imageA = new Mat(mRgba.size(), Core.DEPTH_MASK_ALL);
        hierarchy = new Mat();

        Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, imageHSV, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
        Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imageHSV, imageBlurr, new Size(5,5), 0);
        Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(imageBlurr, imageA, 255,Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY,7, 5);

        List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
        Imgproc.findContours(imageA, contours, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
        //Imgproc.findContours(imageA, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

        level = "" + contours.size();
        setContour();

        imageHSV.release();
        imageBlurr.release();
        imageA.release();
        hierarchy.release();

        return mRgba; 
    }

    public void setContour() {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
             @Override
             public void run() {
                contourCount.setText(level);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the past when creating memory intensive apps I've had to manually increase the amount of memory the app has access to. There may not necessarily be a OOM error, but the app may simply be extremely memory intensive.

Try adding this to your application tag in your manifest:

```
android:largeHeap="true"
```

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Agreed, I've run into similar issues with my apps consuming too much RAM to be allowed to run and similarly crashing.

Comment: I'm testing this now. Is this best practice for setText() then? EDIT: This still crashes without any logcat errors?

Comment: Not sure how similar Android's Dalvik memory space is to Java, but if you're running out of OpenCV native memory on Windows, then increasing your heap can actually cause more OOM errors.  On the JDK you can increase your native memory space with this:   -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=xxxxM

Comment: I'm running the application on my tablet. I"m unsure what you mean by increasing native memory in JDK

Comment: @medloh: I've run into this issue before and increasing the heap solved my issue. If you're suggesting he change "-XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=xxxxM" in the eclipse.ini, that will only affect the memory that the eclipse application has. It has no bearing on the final compiled native application.

Comment: Assuming Android even has that setting, I'm suggesting he experiment running his app with that JVM argument.  That argument controls how much memory OpenCV's native code will have to run in, not the heap.  At least that's how it works with Oracles JVM.

Comment: Another suggestion, I see in your call to findContours() you're creating a new Mat() each time for the hierarchy.  I've had issues with that.  I eventually just defined and initialized a Mat as a class var and reused it in every call to findCoutours().   Most memory issue's I've had in OpenCV came down to either creating too many Mats or creating Mats that were too big.

Comment: @medloh: so you are suggesting that I create Mat hierarchy; and then initialize it in onCreate() ?

Comment: that would work, or you could just initialize it when you declare it:  private Mat matHierch = new Mat();

Comment: @medloh the application crashes if i initialize it when i declare it outside of onCreate

Comment: that probably just means that the OpenCV system hasn't been initialized yet by the time the instance of your class is being created.  You can just instantiate it later as you suggested in onCreate(), or initialize OpenCV earlier, like in a static initializer.

Comment: @medloh this extended the applications life, but I solved the issue by releasing the Mats at the end of onCameraFrame (except mRgba because it needed to be returned). Thank you for your help!